# c++ simple program error

Tags: c++, include, iostream, deprecated

I have created a file called `untitled1.cpp` in dev-cpp with the following script:

```
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "C++";
    return 0;
}
```

But the compiler shows errors like:

> 1 F:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\backward\iostream.h:31,
>   from F:\Dev-Cpp\Untitled1.cpp In file included from
>   include/c++/3.4.2/backward/iostream.h:31,               from
>   F:\Dev-Cpp\Untitled1.cpp  32:2
>   F:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\backward\backward_warning.h #warning This
>   file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header. Please
>   consider using one of the 32 headers found in section 17.4.1.2 of the
>   C++ standard. Examples include substituting the  header for the
>    header for C++ includes, or  instead of the deprecated
>   header . To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.

What is the error that I have? How do I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to get iostream.h](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698267/where-to-get-iostream-h)

Comment: Those are use warning. Still it is complied.

Comment: I always find it funny when "simple errors" are presented. If they are "simple" to you, why can't you fix it yourself?

Comment: @phresnel Gokul might have meant that the program was simple, not the error.

Comment: I think it's funnier that the warning message tells you exactly what's wrong...

Comment: @AndreasBrinck Yeah, but in a very roundabout way. If I got a warning that long, I might scratch my head too!

Comment: The first thing it says is "This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header"

Comment: @MrLister: Admittedly the poster might have thought this. My interpretation was "simple program-error" (and that's a common pattern on forums). However, I agree on Andreas that actually reading error messages is a Good Thing. While me may [not expect users to read stuff](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000062.html), we may do so from programmers.

Comment: @phresnel I know, I also wrote that in my answer ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++ you import the standard library without using the `.h` suffix.

```
#include <iostream>
```

So your fixed example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << "C++";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Gokul Ktp: You are using windows I presume? Use a terminal like cmd.exe to execute your program.

Comment: but the window of my programme appeared and disappeared in a second

Comment: Yes, that's how fast your program runs!

Comment: but i cant see whats inside it

Comment: @GokulKtp have you tried doing it the way nightcracker suggested?

Comment: yeah same thing happened my compiler is dev-c++ version 4.9.9.2

Comment: Oh, the same seven year old compiler that was used in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018207/how-to-increase-stack-size-in-bloodshed-dev-c#comment12810224_10018207)?

Comment: can u pls suggest me anyother good compiler which is available for free

Comment: @GokulKtp: this is easy to download and install and is pretty recent: http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not standard C++. You should say `#include <iostream>` (no ".h"!). Whatever source you have been learning this from is about 25 years out of date, and you should consider getting some more modern material.

(The "iostreams.h" header was part of a very early non-standard library in the early 1990s, and so it's being kept around for "compatibility" reasons, or to catch very inert programmers and give them a helpful hint.)

Comment: @MrLister: Yes. C programmers of the style "I've written that C-with-classes thing when you were still in your diapers, and I'm not going to write it any differently now."

Comment: Ah, OK. I thought you might mean "inept", sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Use header file as `#include<iostream>` instead of `#include<iostream.h>`

Answer (score 1):

Include `iostream` instead of  `iostream.h`

Answer (score 0):

It says that the header, in this case, `iostream.h` is deprecated or antiquated. (You only have one header, so that's the one! Just read the error message!)

So you'll have to use `iostream`, not `iostream.h`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning.

I think that you could try to include `iostream` instead of `iostream.h` in order to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You've posted the reason in your question already!

> This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header.

The real question should therefore be: "Which one is antiquated, how do I replace it?", not "What's the error". Answer: Use `<iostream>`. The `<*.h>` versions are pre-standard, legacy headers.

So: Read error messages, people.